# Proof of dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following:
$$\dim(U+W)+\dim(U\cap W)= \dim U+\dim W$$
I done this by supposing $\dim ( U \cap W)$ to be zero and then opening $\dim U + \dim W$,is it right? If not, correct me with another method.

Comment: Are the spaces of finite dimension?

Comment: You take a basis of $U\cap V$ then extend it to both $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Pick a basis for each space, the union of that basis is a basis for the sum space.

Comment: Mine method is wrong?prove it here plz

Answer (score 2):

It is inappropriate to assume that $\dim(U\cap W)=0.$

Instead, I recommend you proceed as follows:

- Start with a basis $\mathcal B_0$ for $U\cap W.$ (Note that this basis may be the empty set.)
- Extend $\mathcal B_0$ to a basis $\mathcal B_1$ for $U.$
- Extend $\mathcal B_0$ to a basis $\mathcal B_2$ for $W.$
- Let $\mathcal B_3=\mathcal B_1\cup\mathcal B_2.$

Do you see how $\mathcal B_0,\mathcal B_1,\mathcal B_2,$ and $\mathcal B_3$ are related to this problem?

---

**Added**: There are several things you should be able to show (some, simply by definition).

1. Since $\mathcal B_0$ is a basis for $U\cap W,$ then $\dim(U\cap W)=\left\lvert\mathcal B_0\right\rvert.$
2. Since $\mathcal B_1$ is a basis for $U,$ then $\dim(U)=\left\lvert\mathcal B_1\right\rvert.$
3. Since $\mathcal B_2$ is a basis for $W,$ then $\dim(W)=\left\lvert\mathcal B_2\right\rvert.$
4. $\mathcal B_3$ is a basis for $U+W,$ and therefore $\dim(U+W)=\left\lvert\mathcal B_3\right\rvert.$

By the four facts above, we see that the problem amounts to showing that $$\left\lvert\mathcal B_3\right\rvert+\left\lvert\mathcal B_0\right\rvert=\left\lvert\mathcal B_1\right\rvert+\left\lvert\mathcal B_2\right\rvert,$$ or equivalently, that $$\left\lvert\mathcal B_1\cup\mathcal B_2\right\rvert+\left\lvert\mathcal B_0\right\rvert=\left\lvert\mathcal B_1\right\rvert+\left\lvert\mathcal B_2\right\rvert.$$ One more fact you should be able to prove is

5. $\mathcal B_1\cap\mathcal B_2=\mathcal B_0.$

Hence, the problem amounts to proving that $$\left\lvert\mathcal B_1\cup\mathcal B_2\right\rvert+\left\lvert\mathcal B_1\cap\mathcal B_2\right\rvert=\left\lvert\mathcal B_1\right\rvert+\left\lvert\mathcal B_2\right\rvert.$$

For this, we need to prove one final fact:

> If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, then $$|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|.$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30310/discussion-on-answer-by-cameron-buie-proof-of-dimensions).

Answer (score 1):

$$\dim(U+W)= \dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)$$
Does this remind you of any identity?

Proceed by considering the basis of each set(vector space) involved.

Comment: How to start?@Neeraj

Comment: Do you know about quotient spaces?

Comment: No @NeerajKumar

Comment: Well if you would have considered quotient of $U+V, U, V$ by $U\cap V$, then it will be easy. Anyway,what I wanted to say before is in much elaborated form in the answer by @Cameron Buie , try his answer.